# iOS App Update deletes database when migrating more than one database version

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, database-migration, magicalrecord

I'm using magical record in my project and because I needed new columns in my database I made a soft migration by following this tutorial http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-migrations-swift-tutorial/

So I made the changes in the `persistentStoreCoordinator`, added a new model version, set the current model version to the new one and inserted a new attribute and created the new NSManagedObject.

Everything worked fine, so in my next app version I did the same process again because I wanted to add another column.

So I have 3 database versions now.

Then I realized, when updating from an older app version which uses the first database model to the newest one which uses the third database model, all the data gets deleted.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what caused the issue. I did everything fine in the `persistentStoreCoordinator`, so I can recommend the tutorial I linked in my question.
But in my `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I had to change the line `MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack()` to `MagicalRecord.setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack()`